# PhoneGap Bluetooth Plugin on Android device

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins

I've been trying to get a bluetooth plugin for PhoneGap working but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Firstly, my test device is a Galaxy S3 (GT-19305T) and the applications were built using the [PhoneGap CLI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

The plugin I am attempting to use can be found [here](https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin) with an example [here](http://blogit.jamk.fi/metsaapuilta/2013/10/24/bluetooth-for-phonegap/).

I tried the example which didn't seem to actually do anything.

So then I went basic, and tried using the plugins with examples given by PhoneGap. I could quite easily get all of these working. In my example, I am using the basic device information plugin.

Here is some example code:

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
        var btstatus = document.getElementById('status');
        btstatus.innerHTML = "Getting bluetooth information";

        window.bluetooth.isEnabled(isEnabledSuccess, isEnabledError);
    }

    function checkBluetoothStatus() {
        var btstatus = document.getElementById('status');
        btstatus.innerHTML = "Checking bluetooth information";
        window.bluetooth.isEnabled(isEnabledSuccess, isEnabledError);
    }

    function isEnabledSuccess(isEnabled){
       var btstatus = document.getElementById('status');
       if(isEnabled){
         btstatus.innerHTML = "Enabled";
       }else{
         btstatus.innerHTML = "Disabled";
       }
    }

    function isEnabledError(error){
       var btstatus = document.getElementById('status');
       btstatus.innerHTML = "Cannot determine Bluetooth status: " + error.message;
    }

    function enableBluetooth(){
        var btstatus = document.getElementById('status');
        btstatus.innerHTML = "Attempting to turn bluetooth on";
        window.bluetooth.enable(bluetoothTestSucces, bluetoothTestFail);
    }
</script>
```

**Html:**

```
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
    <br />
    <button onclick="enableBluetooth();">Enable Bluetooth</button>
    <br />
    <button onclick="checkBluetoothStatus();">Check Bluetooth Status</button>
    <br />
    <p id="status">Loading bluetooth information...</p>
  </body>
```

So basically I am trying to either get the plugin to return the current bluetooth connectivity information, or enable the bluetooth upon clicking the "enable bluetooth" button.

Unfortunately nothing has worked so far and as I stated earlier I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I have tried applying it manually and by using the CLI.

Comment: Just to make sure, before trying to solve, did you set: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes when I tried manually adding it in eclipse I did, also when using the CLI this is done automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have recently experimented with the same example and was able to get it working. The main difference however is that **I used Cordova CLI instead**.

**Note:** You will need to have installed: Apache ANT, JAVA, Android SDK, GIT Command Line Tool. The first three also need to be set up correctly in your Environment Path.

These are the steps I performed:

1. Download Node.JS (and then run the command prompt)
2. `npm install -g cordova`
3. `npm install -g coffee-script`
4. `cd C:\`
5. `cordova create bluetooth com.example.bluetooth bluetooth`
6. `cd bluetooth`
7. `cordova platform add android`
8. `cordova plugin add https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin.git`
9. Download [this](https://gist.github.com/tanelih/7193921)
10. Covert `main.coffee` to `main.js` using `coffee --compile main.coffee`
11. Download the library files (jQuery, bootstrap, underscore, backbone) and place them in the correct directories
12. Place all of the example documents in the correct directories, and edit index to have `<script src="cordova.js">` instead of `<script src="phonegap.js">`
13. `cordova build android`

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. These are nicely detailed steps of how you built the apk, I followed very similar steps using the phonegap CLI and I'm not too sure why mine wasn't working. The only real difference I can see is the part where you edit the phonegap.js include to cordova.js

Comment: Having some issues here also. I managed to do everything up to the point of building the damn thing. Once I put the apk file on the phone and install it, there is no boostrap layout and everything is disabled, can't click any button. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Stargazer I think the reason everything is disabled is because the buttons are set to disabled by default. They are only enabled once everything is working. It seems something didn't work properly somewhere along the line and thus the buttons aren't getting enabled. You could try manually removing the disable from the buttons but I don't think it will help since the problem will still be there.

Comment: @Yorimitsu, I did managed to put it to work. I was planing to come here and state that. In fact, it had to do with the plugin not being properly configured as a "plugman friendly" plugin on my app and also some other issues with CDN. Now I'm struggling to read binary data with it...But that's another story.

Comment: @Stargazer I am having the same problem as you (buttons are disabled). Could you tell me how you fixed your problem? I am new to mobile programming, and any link about this would be very useful.

Comment: i get processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: isConnected is not defined" at main.js:122:14 
  DeviceListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#list-devices",
    initialize: function() {
      return this.collection.on("reset add", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html("");
      return this.collection.each((function(_this) {
          return function(device) {
          return _this.$el.append(new DeviceView({
            model: device
          }).render().el);  <-------- line 122
        };
      })(this));
    }
  });
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://blogit.jamk.fi/metsaapuilta/2013/10/24/bluetooth-for-phonegap/) article can help? This is more bluetooth connection with others specific then your question, but maybe it can help.I've used it in the past and it worked great with PhoneGap 3.0, only downside was that BlackBerry wasn't compatible anymore.

Comment: This example is what I was using. This is stated at the start of my question.