# error message in cordova bluetooth plugin test script

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I'm trying to get the phone gap bluetooth plugin to access my bluetooth device.

I found this set of instructions:

[PhoneGap Bluetooth Plugin on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259071/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin-on-android-device/20462789#20462789)

and followed the steps in Yorimitsu's answer

I'm having problems getting it to pair with my device.

In the CordovaLog messages in android log cat I see:

```
 file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1075 : 
     processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: isConnected is not defined
 file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1076 : 
     processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: isConnected is not defined
     at HTMLDivElement.eval (eval at <anonymous>
        (file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/underscore.js:5:15110), <anonymous>:8:5)
     at HTMLDivElement.c (file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/underscore.js:5:15203)
     at m.access (file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/jquery.js:4:3496)
     at m.fn.extend.html (file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/jquery.js:4:21736)
     at Backbone.View.extend.render (file:///android_asset/www/js/main.js:47:16)
     at file:///android_asset/www/js/main.js:122:14
     at Function.m.each.m.forEach    
          (file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/underscore.js:5:2350)
     at null.each (file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/backbone.js:1:759)
     at Backbone.View.extend.render (file:///android_asset/www/js/main.js:118:30)
     at p (file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/backbone.js:1:3792)
```

In main.js, line 188 & line 122 are shown below

```
DeviceListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#list-devices",
    initialize: function() {
      return this.collection.on("reset add", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html("");
      return this.collection.each((function(_this) { <----- line 118
          return function(device) {
          return _this.$el.append(new DeviceView({
            model: device
          }).render().el); <------ line 122
        };
      })(this));
    }
  });
```

I'm assuming this is the collection its referencing:

```
DeviceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Device
});
```

and this is the definition of Device:

```
Device = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: "name",
    address: "address",
    isConnected: false
  }
});
```

Here I'm only partially including the definition of DeviceView so you can see main.js line 47 below:

```
DeviceView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: templates.device,
  events: {
    "click .btn-bt-connect": "connect",
    "click .btn-bt-disconnect": "disconnect"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    return this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(_.template(this.template, { <----- line 47
      name: this.model.get("name"),
      isConnected: this.model.get("isConnected")
    }));
    return this;
  },
  connect: function() {
```

If its not already crystal clear, I'm a coffee-script/bootstrap/ underscore/backbone newbie and am at a loss as to what's wrong or how to fix it.

Can anyone explain what they would do faced with a similar problem?

Comment: Execute summary: `_.template(tmpl, data)` doesn't work the way it used to, you want to `t = _.template(tmpl); h = t(data)` now.

Comment: And then do I use "this.$el.html(h)" ?

Comment: Yes, the [documentation for `_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) covers this.